# jenkins remote workspace not working properly

Tags: jenkins

i have configured two machines as node in jenkins , and configured remote workspace /home/jenkins/workpace in each machine , when i try to start a deployment job in one of these node the following error occurs
process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/workspace/tms-flutter-service/tms-flutter-service-deploy@tmp/durable-2879de5c
unning Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer